# android terminal: listing primary activity for an apk

Tags: android, bash, list, shell

I'm trying to write a bash script that will eventually end up in init.d to create an XML file that lists the primary activity for each apk installed as user (not system apps)

So far my output lists all apks in /data/app/ but not activities.

Here is what I have

```
for f in /data/app/*.apk; do
 p=${f%-[0-9].apk}
 e=${p##*/}
 echo "<boolean name=\"$e\" value=\"true\" />" >> /data/AppList.xml
done
```

Comment: Activity names would be stored in AndroidManifest.xml inside the apk. Problem is, once an apk is compiled, that is a binary xml, and you won't be able to read it without something like apk tool to decompile

Comment: Hmm.. any way to get running activities? Or recent? Or anything like that into bash?

Answer (score 1):

Had to look into this because I didn't know, but there are two binaries on the phone that should be a big help I think.

```
pm
```

can list activities for you, you may have to play around to get only the main/launcher activities

```
am
```

can be used to start activities on the command line, if you need that as well

Comment: Pm is listing packages, how do I get activities? Even if its all